# How to calculate Sum of a part of datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview in which the number of columns is dynamic according to the data from the database. The three first columns are used to display name, lastname and fullname and the three last columns to display other people information. I want to calculate for each row the sum between the three first and the three last columns and put the sum in the `Total` column. My result is not correct.

Below is my code:

```
private void DgvPV_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        double Sum = 0;
        int countColumn = DgvPV.ColumnCount;
        int countRow = DgvPV.RowCount;
        int column = countColumn - 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < countRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 3; j < column; j++)
            {
                Sum += Convert.ToDouble(DgvPV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                DgvPV.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value = Sum;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < DgvPV.RowCount; i++)
        {
            DgvPV.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(DgvPV.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value.ToString()) - Convert.ToDouble(DgvPV.Rows[i - 1].Cells["Total"].Value.ToString());
        }              
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erreur de chargement des données... " + ex, "ERREUR DE CONNEXION AU SERVEUR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Paint events are for painting only, and never show a MessageBox in one either.

Comment: Ok I correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to reset the `Sum` variable after computing it in the outer `foreach`. This should be working:

```
double Sum = 0;
int countColumn = DgvPV.ColumnCount;
int countRow = DgvPV.RowCount;
int column = countColumn - 4;
for (int i = 0; i < countRow; i++)
{
    Sum = 0; // Your bug was right here
    for (int j = 3; j < column; j++)
    {
        Sum += Convert.ToDouble(DgvPV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
        DgvPV.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value = Sum;
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i < DgvPV.RowCount; i++)
{
    DgvPV.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(DgvPV.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value.ToString()) - Convert.ToDouble(DgvPV.Rows[i - 1].Cells["Total"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: @Ltazmat then you can mark it as an answer. I am glad it did help you